# Cannot edit RDL report definition form in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, rdlc, rdl

I have several reports I created/edited in visual studio 2013 ULT and all was fine.

Then I upgraded to visual studio 2015 PRO and am on update 3 and I cannot edit the rdl files.

The files open up in the IDE, but the no report controls are visible and I cannot add any additional controls in the designer.

I can view the XML files (obviously) and I can edit/manage dataset, parameters, data sources, etc but not the actual report itself.

I can even preview the report in the IDE, I just can't edit it

Here is what I have done so far:

- I have installed SSDT for visual studio 2015
- I have modified the default installation of visual studio
- I have run the IDE in admin mode
- I have renamed the rds files to rdlc and rdls (RDLC just throws an error and RDLS will only open in XML)